# About expansive homeomorphim

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, dynamical-systems

We say $(X,f)$ is expansive if there is $c(f)>0$ such that if $d(f^{n}(x), f^{n}(y))< c(f)$ for every $n\in Z$ then $y=x$.
Let $(X,f)$ is expansive with constant $c(f)$ and for infinite set $\{n_k \}$,  $d(f^{n_k}(x), f^{n_k}(y))< c(f).$

My question is if $x=y$? ($x,y$ are not periodic points)

Comment: What are $X$ and $f$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: $\langle X,d\rangle$ is a metric space, and $f:X\to X$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @GPerez: You’ve misunderstood the definition. Let me restate it in a different form: there is a positive constant $\epsilon$, depending only on $f$, such that whenever $x$ and $y$ are distinct points of $X$, there is an $n\in\Bbb Z$ such that $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))\ge\epsilon$. The map $f(x)=2x$ on the positive reals is an example.

Comment: @GPerez: No correction is needed: the OP’s definition is equivalent to mine.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily.  Let $X=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ be the space of all bi-infinite sequences of symbols $0$ and $1$ with the metric
$$
   d(x,y) := 2^{-\inf\{|i|: x_i\neq y_i\}}
$$
(with $\inf\varnothing:=\infty$), which induces the product topology.  Let $f$ be the shift map defined by $(f(x))_i:=x_{i+1}$.  Note that $d(f^n(x),f^n(y))<1$ if and only if $x_n=y_n$.  So, $(X,f)$ is expansive with constant $1$.  Now, choose two sequences $x$ and $y$ that are distinct but agree on infinitely many positions $\{n_k\}$.

Comment: Dear Prof. Blackbird, Thanks a lot for your reply